# How to make a deleted message logger in Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I am working on making this bot, and I need to know how to make a deleted message logger. I am using discord.js v12 and want the logs to go to this channel with the ID `713570869305409566`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`messageDelete`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageDelete) event

```js
bot.on('messageDelete', message => {
  const embed = new MessageEmbed() // or `new Discord.MessageEmbed()` depending on how you imported `discord.js`
    .setAuthor(`${message.author.username} (${message.author.id})`, message.author.avatarURL())
    .setDescription(message.content)

  const channel = bot.channels.cache.get('713570869305409566')
  channel.send(embed)
})
```

Comment: "client" is not defined, here are my consts:

const Discord = require('discord.js') |
const bot = new Discord.Client(); |
const admin = '713787463331741726';

Comment: sorry, fixed the answer

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined. This comes from this code: Discord.channels.cache.get('713570869305409566')

Comment: why did you type `Discord.channels` when the answer says `bot.channels`?

Comment: Wait, I put bot.channels, it gave me an error for something that's not there.

Comment: channel.send(embed) | TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined @Syntle

Comment: Hmm, for some reason it wasn't. Thank you!